# Saving base64EncodedString of UIImage to Realm

Tags: ios, swift, base64

I try to save base64EncodedString to my RealmSwift.

```
let encodeBase64_Full = (imageData! as NSData).base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
```

But base64EncodedString so long and it consumes too much memory.

[image: length of base64EncodedString]

So, how can I save it with shortly length.

Thanks all.

Comment: Is `imageData.length` big too? If YES, how is `encodeBase64_Full` supposed to be really shorter?

Comment: @Larme yes, imageData.length is big too. The image is about 1.5 Mb

Answer (score 1):

First just compress image with

> let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgProfile.image!, 0.50)

And then after convert image data to Base64image.It reduce string length and Memory issue. Like this:

> str64BaseImg = (imgData?.base64EncodedString(options:
>   .lineLength64Characters))!

Comment: for 48 hours I was fighting with API ! 
When I get the 64BaseString from my code it working fine , but when I got it from Realm file it give me Error 500 !

I was using '.endLineWithLineFeed' when I converted it to `.lineLength64Characters `
It fixed my problem ! , thank you !!